# How to compare dates in Python only with mm--dd from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataset with 69000 rows and 18 columns. One on the columns is datetime which is in this format yyyy-mm-dd with the time.
What I dont know to do is the next problem
I need to create a new column ("Seasson") with the value "high" if the value in datetime is between 05-13 (mm-dd) and 07-18 (mm-dd)

```
for d in df_prueba['Fecha_Tiem']:
   df_prueba['date'] = d.date()
   df_prueba['time'] = d.time()
```

All I did is to separate the datetime in date and time but I dont know how to get only the month and day from date and use it to compare with the previous date

Answer (score 1):

using the `strftime()` method, which formats a `datetime` object as a string. You can then compare the resulting string with the strings "05-13" and "07-18" to determine whether the date falls within the desired range.

Here's an example i found in google

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2022-05-12 08:00:00', '2022-07-19 14:00:00', '2022-06-15 12:00:00']})

# convert the datetime column to a datetime object
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

# extract the month and day from the datetime column and convert it to a string
df['month_day'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')

    # create a new column 'Season' based on the month and day
    df.loc[(df['month_day'] >= '05-13') & (df['month_day'] <= '07-18'), 'Season'] = 'high'
    df.loc[df['Season'].isnull(), 'Season'] = 'low'
    
    print(df)
```

Outpu :

```
             datetime month_day Season
0 2022-05-12 08:00:00     05-12   high
1 2022-07-19 14:00:00     07-19    low
2 2022-06-15 12:00:00     06-15   high
```